# Подключить gsm модем на роутере с Advanced Tomato прошивкой

Tags: usb, asterisk

Привет всем!

Хочу подключить gsm модем. Но не пойму что указывать в конфигурационном файле chan_dongle.conf. Через какие файлы устройств астериск будет коннектиться к модему.

В CentOS, на котором этот модем работал раньше, он определялся тремя устройствами `/dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2`.

Но на роутере моём `ASUS RT-N18U` с установленной прошивкой Advanced Tomato нет устройств `/dev/ttyUSB*`. При подключении модема в `/var/log/message` вижу:

```
May 27 10:23:00 unknown kern.info kernel: usb 2-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5829]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.0 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5835]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.1 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5836]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.2 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
```

Вижу новый character device в `/dev`:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 131 May 27 10:23 usbdev2.4
```

Но он один и астериск не может к нему подключиться:

```
[May 27 07:33:06] WARNING[6233]: chan_dongle.c:235 opentty: tcgetattr() failed for /dev/usbdev2.4: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

В чём может быть дело? Как найти те 3 `/dev/ttyUSB*` устройства на роутере с прошивкой Tomato, которые у меня были на CentOS?

Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Единственное решение это использовать перебор. Смотрим все устройства - ls -lh /dev/ , после чего к каждому подключаемся командой screen /dev/ttyUSBномер и смотрим что отдает в консоль ,если это модем то что-то выдаст. Так же надо проверить права, иногда не работает подключение, сделайте chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSBномер, после чего опять пробуйте подключиться

Comment: Ок, только что перебирать? Одно устройство в /dev появляется. Эти: 2-2:1.0, 2-2:1.1, 2-2:1.2 тоже есть в /sys/... Но я не нашел там файлов устройств.

Comment: дополнил комментарий

Comment: /dev/ttyUSB* -- такого нет.

Comment: пробуйте все tty по очереди. Странно что нет юсб, возможно  модем даже не примонтировался

Comment: Возможно прошивка не увидела модем как модем. Например, это может быть из-за того, что она не знает соответствующий dev/ven id - тогда остается ручками их прописать Вот здесь, например, - http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/current-usb-3g-modem-support.35574/ все определяется как надо - как ttyUSBномер
А бывает еще, что нужно сделать modeswitch, т.к. модем хитрый и по умолчанию определяется как флэшка.

Comment: Modeswitch сделан, на компе с Centos модем определяется как 3 устройства. На роутере тоже как 3 устройства, видно из лога /var/log/message но не монитруется как ttyUSB. Появляется только /dev/usbdev2.3 при подключении. Причем при отключении модема он не пропадает, а при повторном подключении модема появляется новый  /dev/usbdev2.4. Может драйверов каких-то нету... Где их искать? Где ручками прописывать dev/ven id?

Comment: В выводе команды cat /proc/bus/usb/devices вижу что Driver=(none) у моего gsm модема. А на компе где он определяется Driver=option. Посмотрел на роутере в  "/lib/modules/2.6.36.4brcmarm/kernel/drivers/usb" option.ko есть.